# Building DataFrames from gz and json files

Tags: python

This is part of my code.

1. List all files and read them into the list `files`.
2. Now I have a dictionary `my_dict`. The values are the parquet files. all files must have **same schema**.
3. I have more than 2000 files is my folder, so `files` is large.
4. For each file I firstly `gunzip` all of them.
5. Next I find all the JSON files.
6. Problem is here. My file `tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T01-02-58.json` will be read and converted to dateframe and appended to `'tick-2.parquet'`.

My code works but the execution time is very low. How do I get rid of one or more loops?

```
def gunzip(file_path, output_path):
    with gzip.open(file_path, "rb") as f_in:
        with open(output_path, "wb") as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = os.listdir('/Users/milenko/mario/Json_gzips')
    files = [fi for fi in files if fi.endswith(".gz")]

    my_dict = {'ticr_calculated_2': 'ticr-2.parquet', 'ticr_calculated_3': 'ticr-3.parquet', \
               'ticr_calculated_4': 'ticr-4.parquet', 'tick_calculated_2': 'tick-2.parquet', \
               'tick_calculated_3': 'tick-3.parquet', 'tick_calculated_4': 'tick-4.parquet'}
    basic = '/Users/milenko/mario/Json_gzips/'

    for file in files:
        gunzip(file, file.replace(".gz", ""))

        json_fi = glob.glob("*.json")

        for key, value in my_dict.items():
            filepath = basic + value
            for f in json_fi:
                if key in f:
                    result_df = pd.DataFrame()
                    with open(f, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as i:
                        data = pd.read_json(i, lines=True)
                        result_df = result_df.append(data)
                        table_from_pandas = pa.Table.from_pandas(result_df)
                        pq.write_table(table_from_pandas, filepath)
```

Comment: The `file` variable is only used on the first line of the outer loop. Why is the rest of the code also in the loop?

Comment: Indentation error.

Comment: @JanneKarila Take a look now. How should I initialize my result_df? something is wrong. I want to read files into pd.dataframe and save them to respective parquet files.